# grails remotefunction: can't access params

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails, dojo

I've got a remoteFunction call in a javaScript function in my GSP file:

```
function fnCreateEntitiesPerForceChart() {
      var interval = $("#entitiesPerForceTimeIntervalSelect").val();
      interval = escape(interval);
      var url = '${createLink(controller: 'federation', action: 'createEntitiesPerForceChart')}?interval='+interval;
      $("#entitiesPerForceChart").attr("src", url);
alert("interval is: " + interval);
      ${remoteFunction(controller: 'federation', 
        action: 'getEntitiesPerForceTable', 
        params: '\'interval\''+':'+interval, 
        onSuccess: 'fnUpdateEntitiesPerForceTable(data,textStatus)')}; 
    }
```

When I check the page source, the remotefunction creates this code:

```
try{DojoGrailsSpinner.show();}catch(e){} dojo.xhr('Get',{content:{'interval':null}, preventCache:true, url:'/FederationReporter/federation/getEntitiesPerForceTable', load:function(response){  fnUpdateEntitiesPerForceTable(data,textStatus); }, handle:function(response,ioargs){try{DojoGrailsSpinner.hide();}catch(e){} }, error:function(error,ioargs){try{DojoGrailsSpinner.hide();}catch(e){}  } });;
```

Why is my variable being replaced with 'null'?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot find your function call within the page source. The function `fnUpdateEntitiesPerForceTable` is called while your function is called `fnCreateEntitiesPerForceChart`. Can you explain your problem a bit more detailed?

Comment: Am I right to assume you are using both the Jquery and the dojo plugin at the same time ? If not, then most likely you are using the dojo plugin alone and trying to use jquery syntax for your selectors, which is likely to not work...

Answer (score 0):

Try this as `params` in `remoteFunction` call

`params: '\'interval\': + interval'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function fnCreateEntitiesPerForceChart() {
  var interval = dojo.byId("entitiesPerForceTimeIntervalSelect").get("value");
  // [...] rest of your code
}
```